# redirect after login to next if next points to logout

Tags: django

django has elegant way to redirect (after some action, for example `login`) to the previous page:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">{% trans 'sign in' %}</a>
```

which works absolutely fine unless the previous page happens to be `logout` page.

is there a way to implement more advanced logic for `next`? like the following

```
if next is 'logout' or 'something_else':
    redirect to constant path
else:
    redirect to the previous location
```

thank you!

Comment: It might be easier to remove the `next` parameter from the template if you are on the logout page: `{% if not "logout" in request.path %}?next={{ request.path }}{% endif %}`

Comment: great! this is indeed the easiest way! thank you

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can close off hte question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is easier to remove the `next` parameter from the template if you are currently on the logout page:

```
{% if not "logout" in request.path %}?next={{ request.path }}{% endif %}
```